# Do Thunderhawks or similar shuttles have an auto-pilot?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Do [Thunderhawk gunships](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Thunderhawk) or similar smaller void capable astartes shuttles have any kind of auto-pilot, or any way to fly without someone trained in piloting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Depends on What Your View of Autopilot is**

Firstly there's the machine spirit, but as mentioned in Shade's comment even the most advanced ones don't seem capable of flying themselves.  At best you might get something like a Corvus Blackstar (special elite/sophisticated transport for the Deathwatch, themselves an elite subset of Astartes) being able to pull off an automated takeoff/landing similar to how a Harrier jump-jet can perform VTOL (Vertical TakeOff/Landing) with minimal input on the part of the pilot.  But as far as "go from point A to point B" a machine spirit won't get you there.  Which leaves...

Hard-wired Servitors.  These guys are the business.  In *Salvation's Reach*  a Caestus assault ram is piloted solely by a servitor that's hard-wired into the cockpit.  A servitor is a lobotomized human being, and in this case (because we know it's hard-wired) cannot exist without the ship it's wired into.  They often have mechanical augmentations, but in this instance (apart from being stuck in the pilot's chair) we don't know if it received cranial implants or has its eyes wired to the Caestus' cameras or what have you.  Servitors are programmable, and can perform various functions depending on capabilities.  In this particular instance the servitor-equipped assault ram was able to A: Navigate a dense debris field to target. B: deviate slightly from programmed approach to land at a more suitable site that wasn't identified pre-flight. and C: engage the enemy with main gun fire as threats appeared.

All that is pretty standard "sci-fi autopilot" stuff.  Just that in 40k it's "wetware" because of the Imperium's prohibition against thinking machines without organic components.  Given the rarity of Astartes and the fact they're more use as infantry than crewmen, lots of Astartes vehicles are operated wholly or in part by servitors.  A lot depends on the chapter (Space Wolves always fly their own Thunderhawks, other Chapters use servitors in certain instances) but theoretically any vessel or vehicle in the space marine armory can be crewed by servitors.  they'd just be at a disadvantage because super-reflexes-super-soldiers > not-quite-corpse that gets its orders installed via punchcard.

There are several other instances of servitors hard-wired into various vehicles that are simpler in operation.  A train system in another *Gaunt's Ghosts* book that runs automatically via servitor, rickshaws operated by lobotomized ogryn servitors (I want to say in a Ravenor/Eisenhorne book?) that go to streets they're told, etc.  but the Caestus from *Salvation's Reach* seemed most likely to answer your question directly.

Comment: Great answer, specially for being your first one!

Comment: @Shade This isn't their first answer, they create a new unregistered account for every answer they post. There's nothing wrong with doing so, and I know of a few others who do the same.

Comment: @F1Krazy Still a great answer

Answer (score 4):

In theory, yes. That would simply be a machine spirit (emphasis by me):

> *The advanced system consists of a combination of organic and mechanical components within the vehicle and in essence act as automated systems.* Not all vehicles are equipped with such systems, but vehicles that are can operate entirely on their own without a crew, with some success. The Adeptus Mechanicus believes that Machine Spirits can be influenced by religious rituals and are near-bestial in nature, capable of exhibiting emotions such as hatred and stubbornness. In particular, the machine spirits of Titans and Knights are revered for their intensity and require elaborate awakening and taming rituals. With devices such as the Throne Mechanicum, pilots of these engines can link with a Machine Spirit directly.
>
> The addition of a machine spirit is advantageous in the case of the vehicle's crew being killed or incapacitated, as the auto-systems are able to take control of the vehicle, firing its weapons and driving (providing the systems themselves are still functional). The machine spirit however cannot fully replace the abilities of trained human pilots (going that far might trespass on the Imperium's condemnation of Abominable Intelligences, and could garner the attention of the Inquisition).
>
> From the Lexicanum [Article on Machine Spirit](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Machine_spirit)

However, if you continue to read the article, you immediately come upon this:

> Two of the most advanced and powerful types of machine spirit are those found within Land Raiders and Drop Pods. A drop pod uses its abilities to handle course corrections and to avoid collisions into dangerous terrain or anti-aircraft fire.

So, one of the most advanced system is within drop pods and can handle course corrections. However, the drop pod has one direction: down. Therefore, the Machine Spirit can only go a bit only marginaly adapt the course. With the Land Raiders, it's all on a two dimensional map with no changing gravity, asteroids and so on. And those are one of the most advanced. I therefore doubt that a Machine Spirit is able to steer a gunship through the void (that is IMHO rather easy), steer through asteroid fields, enter and exit the atmosphere and land the aircraft.

There might be some auto-pilot actions it can undertake, i.e. keep flying on a predetermined path. But you better check the path first and make sure there is nothing more complicated than some points to change direction on. As mentioned, I highly doubt that a Machine Spirit can fully automatically avoid asteroids in an asteroid field and other complicated tasks.